# MacBook starts to boot but kernel panics before OS loads, works after reinstall until reboot

Tags: macos, startup

For the past 2 weeks I've had a problem: my MacBook Pro starts to boot but doesn't load the OS. I think it is a kernel panic. Here is a photo from the verbose boot.

[image]

The only way to fix it is to restore the OS from cmd+r menu, but then when I power off my Mac, with the next boot, all is like before.

MacBook Pro (15-inch, Mid 2012), macOS Sierra 10.12.4

Comment: That sounds like a hard drive issue.  Have a look at this post - https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/260139/119271  Also, try starting in Safe Mode (hold Shift while booting) to see if the problem goes away

Comment: I've made a scan with techtool pro 9 and all seems good. Here you can see a video of my problem: https://goo.gl/XqY1RE

Comment: And here https://goo.gl/z1Iz84 the scan of EtreCheck. I don't see any hd problem

Comment: Remove one of the 8 GB RAM modules and try to reboot.

Comment: Good, i've done it. Lets see it tomorrow it give problems again or not. I've always have 16gb ram and I never had problem. I've did also a techtool pro 9 check and no problems was individuated.

Comment: If you find that the problem returns, then also try removing the other 8GB RAM module and reinserting the first one.

Comment: Ok! I've just try to power on and all seems good. This evening when i'll come home, I'll try again. Why you advice me to remove it? Do you see something?

Comment: I've an update: without one 8gb ram module, tuxera ntfs and parallels all seems good. Yesterday, I've try to setup parallels with windows 10 and the problem come back. So now I'm removing parallels and keeping tuxera and only one 8gb ram module. Is it possible that the problem was generated by parallels and not by both 8gb ram module?

Comment: Here you can see what Safe mode boot give in output: (https://goo.gl/O4XJJD). It seems that the problem can be generated by: "ng.uds.netusb.controller"