# Could not read LR from frame at 0x0000700005dc3ca8

Tags: hard-drive, kernel-panic

My MacBook locks up and shuts down. I have read numerous threads but haven't been able to get the info to fix this.

I do get this error;

```
Root disk errors: "Could not recover SATA HDD after 5 attempts. Terminating."
```

I have an aftermarket HD. I installed this a few years ago. so other than the HD going bad not sure what else it could be.

I had El Capitan installed when this originated. I just recently installed Sierra.

```
Anonymous UUID:       DB85C25A-DACB-9477-FE00-F424E6DDED2F

Fri Aug  4 14:19:36 2017

*** Panic Report ***
panic(cpu 2 caller 0xffffff801336b46f): initproc exited  -- exit reason namespace 2 subcode 0xa description: none

uuid info:
 0x110bb6000    uuid = <322c06b7-8878-311d-888c-c8fd2ca96ff3>
 0x10791a000    uuid = <0ac314b8-c89c-3912-8bb7-e3f92c847169>

Thread 5 crashed

RAX: 0x000000010791a000, RBX: 0x00007fffcc0eb108, RCX: 0x00007fffcc0eb108, RDX: 0x0000000110bf5978
RSP: 0x00007000060527e0, RBP: 0x00007000060527e0, RSI: 0x00000000000016f7, RDI: 0x0000000110bf8b18
R8:  0x00007fffcc0eb139, R9:  0x0000000000000000, R10: 0x0000000004001080, R11: 0x000000010795e188
R12: 0x0000000110bf8b18, R13: 0x00007ff8b202fa00, R14: 0x00000000000016f7, R15: 0x0000000110bf5978
RFL: 0x0000000000010206, RIP: 0x0000000110bc9fd4, CS:  0x000000000000002b, SS:  0x0000000000000023

Thread 0: 0xffffff801f0c34e8
    0x00007fffcc216386
      Could not read LR from frame at 0x0000700005dc3ca8

Thread 1: 0xffffff801f5e5050
    0x00007fffcc21e1e6
    0x00007fffcc0c724f
    0x0000000000000000

Thread 2: 0xffffff8020c0ddf0
    0x00007fffcc21f6ae
    0x00007fffcc0cea16
    0x00007fffcc0c4a6c
    0x00007fffcc0bc13b
    0x00007fffcc0cf7db
    0x00007fffcc0c2306
    0x00007fffcc0bb6b5
    0x00007fffcc0bb48c
    0x00007fffcc3085a2
    0x00007fffcc30807d
    0x0000000000000000

Thread 3: 0xffffff8023349b90
    0x00007fffcc308070

Thread 4: 0xffffff8023c19510
    0x0000000110bc9fd4
    0x0000000110bd2f8b
    0x0000000110bba86d
    0x00007fffcc0eb282
    0x000000010795e188
    0x00000001079459cd
    0x00007fffcc0b98fc
    0x00007fffcc0cea16
    0x00007fffcc0c4a6c
    0x00007fffcc0bc13b
    0x00007fffcc0cf7db
    0x00007fffcc0c2306
    0x00007fffcc0bb6b5
    0x00007fffcc0bb48c
    0x00007fffcc3085a2
    0x00007fffcc30807d
    0x0000000000000000

Thread 5: 0xffffff8023c14b90
    0x0000000110bc9fd4
    0x0000000110bd2f8b
    0x0000000110bba86d
    0x00007fffcc0eb282
    0x000000010795e188
    0x0000000107929510
    0x00007fffcc0b98fc
    0x00007fffcc0cea16
    0x00007fffcc0c4a6c
    0x00007fffcc0bc13b
    0x00007fffcc0cf7db
    0x00007fffcc0c2306
    0x00007fffcc0bb6b5
    0x00007fffcc0bb48c
    0x00007fffcc3085a2
    0x00007fffcc30807d
    0x0000000000000000


Mac OS version:
16G29

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 16.7.0: Thu Jun 15 17:36:27 PDT 2017; root:xnu-3789.70.16~2/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: D3314D98-5D40-3CD8-98A4-F1DD46C20E03
System model name: MacBookPro6,2 (Mac-F22586C8)
Root disk errors: "Could not recover SATA HDD after 5 attempts. Terminating."
Model: MacBookPro6,2, BootROM MBP61.0057.B1C, 2 processors, Intel Core i7, 2.66 GHz, 4 GB, SMC 1.58f17
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics, Intel HD Graphics, Built-In
Graphics: NVIDIA GeForce GT 330M, NVIDIA GeForce GT 330M, PCIe, 512 MB
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 2 GB, DDR3, 1067 MHz, 0x802C, 0x384A53463235363634485A2D314731443120
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 2 GB, DDR3, 1067 MHz, 0x802C, 0x384A53463235363634485A2D314731443120
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x93), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (5.106.98.100.26)
Bluetooth: Version 5.0.5f1, 3 services, 27 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en1
Serial ATA Device: SanDisk SDSSDXPS960G, 960.2 GB
Serial ATA Device: MATSHITADVD-R   UJ-898
USB Device: USB 2.0 Bus
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: Card Reader
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad
USB Device: BRCM2070 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
USB Device: USB 2.0 Bus
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: USB Receiver
USB Device: IR Receiver
USB Device: Built-in iSight
Thunderbolt Bus:
```

Answer (score 1):

> so other than the HD going bad not sure what else it could be.

The first rule of diagnostics is to not overlook the obvious.  So, the very first thing that you should do is **diagnose the hard drive**.

- Run [Apple Hardware Test (AHT)](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201257).  Hold the D key while booting from a powered off state with the AC adapter connected and run the tests associated with the disk drive
- Boot into recovery mode or with a USB installer (preferred) and via terminal issue the command `diskutil info diskX | grep -i smart` where diskX is the identifier of the drive in question.  To get this issue the command `diskutil list`

Once you have determined the viability of your drive, then you can move on to what the other ailments could possibly be.  Chances are, you will need to [replace your hard drive because it's failing.](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/260141/119271).  You mentioned that you already changed the HDD to an aftermarket one "a few years ago."  Depending on the brand and quality of the drive you may already be outside it's useful life.

Comment: Unable to get to the diagnostics. When I try It just comes up with a triangle with a Asterisk in it and just does nothing. The SSD actually has a 10 year warranty on it. One thing I did find is that the intake for the cooling fans had a large amount of debris. I vacuumed that out. Haven't seen the error yet would normally happen within 1/2hr of use. The funny thing is I ran into this a few years ago on my brother in-laws computer and that caused a lot of issues due to over heating. I don't have a recovery USB I will be taking care of that tonight! Thanks for the input

Comment: Is it a HDD or SDD?  It's an important and significant difference.  If you can run it for a half hour or so, you should be able to execute the commands I posted directly from the booted OS.

Comment: its a San Disk Extreme Pro SSD. So when I try to hold down the D. It just comes up with the triangle with the asterisk in the middle below that it has apple.com/support -3403D. I read on another forum that on the older mac it may require a utility disk to get to the diagnostics

Comment: I believe that's correct - you will need the "Installation Disk 2" which contains the AHT software.  Instead, try [DiskDrill](https://www.cleverfiles.com/) - the diagnostic tools are free.  But to fully test it out, you will need your install disks.

Comment: looks like I will have to take it to apple store. I cant find the original disks. Thanks for the help.