# MacBook Pro crashes intermittently

Tags: mac, crash

My Mid-2014 15" MBP has been randomly crashing and I haven't been able to identify a pattern to the crashes.

Here's a log right after a crash and automatic restart:

```
Anonymous UUID:       D3129405-6FEF-9C3C-46B9-EE344C1D6251

Wed Aug 30 09:41:25 2017

*** Panic Report ***
panic(cpu 7 caller 0xffffff801d96b46f): initproc exited  -- exit reason namespace 2 subcode 0xa description: none

uuid info:
 0x1043fe000    uuid = <322c06b7-8878-311d-888c-c8fd2ca96ff3>
 0x1033bb000    uuid = <0ac314b8-c89c-3912-8bb7-e3f92c847169>

Thread 3 crashed

RAX: 0x00000001033bb000, RBX: 0x00007fffba03e108, RCX: 0x00007fffba03e108, RDX: 0x000000010443d978
RSP: 0x0000700005d66f30, RBP: 0x0000700005d66f30, RSI: 0x000000000000018e, RDI: 0x0000000104440b18
R8:  0x00007fffba03e139, R9:  0x0000700005d67340, R10: 0x0000000000000000, R11: 0x00000001033ff188
R12: 0x0000000104440b18, R13: 0x0000000000000000, R14: 0x000000000000018e, R15: 0x000000010443d978
RFL: 0x0000000000010202, RIP: 0x0000000104411fd4, CS:  0x000000000000002b, SS:  0x0000000000000023

Thread 0: 0xffffff803de054e8
    0x00007fffba169386
      Could not read LR from frame at 0x0000700005bdeca8

Thread 1: 0xffffff803de02260
    0x00007fffba1711e6
    0x00007fffba01a24f
    0x0000000000000000

Thread 2: 0xffffff804305c288
    0x00007fffba1726ae
    0x00007fffba021a16
    0x00007fffba017a6c
    0x00007fffba00f13b
    0x00007fffba0227db
    0x00007fffba015306
    0x00007fffba00e6b5
    0x00007fffba00e48c
    0x00007fffba25b5a2
    0x00007fffba25b07d
    0x0000000000000000

Thread 3: 0xffffff804305b958
    0x0000000104411fd4
    0x000000010441af8b
    0x000000010440286d
    0x00007fffba03e282
    0x00000001033ff188
    0x00000001033ebe09
    0x00007fffba00c8fc
    0x00007fffba021a16
    0x00007fffba017a6c
    0x00007fffba00f13b
    0x00007fffba0227db
    0x00007fffba015306
    0x00007fffba02324c
    0x00007fffba02627a
    0x00007fffba25b47b
    0x00007fffba25b07d
    0x0000000103411000

Thread 4: 0xffffff80605d4078
    0x00007fffba25b070

Thread 5: 0xffffff806318f498
    0x00007fffba251bc1
    0x00007fffba251b59
    0x00000001033e9590
    0x00007fffba021486
    0x00007fffba00c8fc
    0x00007fffba0229a0
    0x00007fffba015306
    0x00007fffba00e6b5
    0x00007fffba00e48c
    0x00007fffba25b5a2
    0x00007fffba25b07d
    0x0000000000000000


Mac OS version:
16G29

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 16.7.0: Thu Jun 15 17:36:27 PDT 2017; root:xnu-3789.70.16~2/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: D3314D98-5D40-3CD8-98A4-F1DD46C20E03
System model name: MacBookPro11,2 (Mac-3CBD00234E554E41)
Root disk errors: "Could not recover SATA HDD after 5 attempts. Terminating."
Model: MacBookPro11,2, BootROM MBP112.0138.B40, 4 processors, Intel Core i7, 2.2 GHz, 16 GB, SMC 2.18f15
Graphics: Intel Iris Pro, Intel Iris Pro, Built-In
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D54343147533641465238412D50422020
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D54343147533641465238412D50422020
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x134), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.21.171.130.1a1)
Bluetooth: Version 5.0.5f1, 3 services, 27 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en0
Serial ATA Device: APPLE SSD SM0256F, 251 GB
USB Device: USB 3.0 Bus
USB Device: Card Reader
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad
USB Device: BRCM20702 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 17.1
```

I followed the troubleshooting suggestions in comments, but the disk appears to be ok. Is there anything else I can do myself before heading to an Apple Store? (The MBP is out of warranty)

Comment: First thing to do is [search](https://apple.stackexchange.com/search?q=random+crash) to see if this question has already been asked. Secondly, when phrasing a question it's important to provide specifics like what version of macOS you are using.  Details are important, as we aren't there to look over your shoulder.

Comment: Of course I did a search first and didn't find a thread similar to my situation. 
In the attached log you can find all the necessary info.

Comment: Interesting...Doing a [Bing](https://www.bing.com/search?q=Could+not+read+LR+from+frame&PC=U316&FORM=CHROMN) search, I found this [link](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/295113/could-not-read-lr-from-frame-at-0x0000700005dc3ca8) (very first link).  Try the diagnostic procedures outlined in the answer there.

Comment: The fact that you are experienced in debugging mac crash logs doesn't mean all of us are. You may know immediately where to look in a file full of random numbers, but I don't. If you want to be a helpful member of the community, show some empathy and cut the ironic talk. 

Other than that, thanks for pointing me out to the correct (I hope) direction.

Comment: Don't do that.  Searching for "initproc exited " in the line right after "Panic Report" would bring up a slew of info including that link.  Our [How to Ask](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) in the Help Section specifically details this.  Finally, you asked for a "direction," does the term "error" in the log not fit that qualification?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Digging up this old question to add an answer, as it might help someone in the future.

What did the trick was to take the MacBook to a 3rd-party repair shop, where they took the internals apart and **cleaned the SSD connection to the motherboard**. After that I’ve been using the laptop for the past 2 months with not a single freeze .

However, the above begs the question how did the SSD connection get dirty? But let’s leave it at that.

Answer (score 1):

What you are experiencing is called a “kernel panic”.

The line `Root disk errors: "Could not recover SATA HDD after 5 attempts. Terminating."`is a clear indication of your MacBook having an issue with the built-in SSD. Are you sure you had a look at the results of Disk First Aid, preferably run from the Recovery HD? As an alternative, you might want to boot into single-user mode (pressing cmd-S upon start) and use `fsck` to test the drive:

```
fsck -f
```

Use the `reboot` command once `fsck` has finished.

Has the MBP ever been opened or dropped? In that case, the SSD may just sit improperly in its slot which would explain the intermittent nature of the symptom. Unlikely but not impossible.

Comment: - Running Apple Diagnostics returns: **No issues found** Reference code: ADP000

- Running First Aid from Recovery (Verify/Repair) returns: The volume Macintosh HD appears to be OK 

- Running `fsck -f` returns: The volume Macintosh HD appears to be OK (after all the checks)

The MBP has been taken really good care of and was chiefly used on a work desk for about a year and a half. I wouldn't suppose this is an issue of mistreatment.

Comment: In this case it might be worth taking a full backup, completely erasing the disk and restoring from the backup taken previously. Not something done with levity, though.

Comment: Should have mentioned it in the original post but I've already done this. I've also completely formatted the disk and cleanly installed macOS but it still froze. It even froze in a Windows bootcamp installation.  

The problem is I cannot reproduce it. It happens randomly (hence the question title), that's why I'm looking for a way to understand what's the issue, so if I was to take it to the store, to give them some heads-up and not have it returned with the claim "It works perfectly".

Comment: @ModestosKaffes I'm having the same issue as you. So far everything seems to be pointing to either the SSD itself or the onboard controller being faulty. Have you tried installing macOS on an external drive and seeing if the problem arises again? Alas, there doesn't seem to be anyone with a definitive solution to this issue.

Comment: Also are the S.M.A.R.T readings showing up any errors?

Comment: @NajmSheikh good thought, I'll try with an external drive too. And no, the S.M.A.R.T reading just showed "Verified".